# GRE subject exam 0568 Q.40

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, gre-exam

This is the question with its answer:
[image]
[image]

I want a justification why I should exclude the other choices, can anyone help me? I am sure that my thinking will not be so clear to provide the example given in the answer at once.

Comment: (A) The field of complex numbers has no non-trivial zero divisors. (B) $\mathbb{Z}/11$ is a field, hence again no zero-divisors. Etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Um, okay so you know that in an integral domain the product of 2 non-zero elements can't be $0$. You also know that every field is also an integral domain.
Now,

a) $\mathbb{C}$ is a field

b) Integers modulo a prime numbers form a field. 11 is a prime

d) Again, this is also a field, as can be shown with little work.

e) $\mathbb{R}[X]$ is an integral domain. Can be easily proved and is well known.